# WSO2 org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 412 Error: Precondition Failed

Tags: web-services, soap, wso2, wso2-esb

I'm using WSO2 ESB and I created a custom proxy service with a WSDL. I defined the InSequence in line as a log mediator defined the endpoint as a Address endpoint and defined the OutSequence as Send mediator when I try the service I got this error:

```html
<TryitProxyError xmlns:h="http://wso2.org/ns/TryitProxy" h:status="SOAP envelope error">org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: Transport error: 412 Error: Precondition Failed</TryitProxyError>
```

How can I fix this error please? I have no idea. Thanks :)

```
org.apache.axis2.AxisFault
    at org.apache.axis2.AxisFault.makeFault(AxisFault.java:430)
    at consultardatosmaestros.CU677ConsultarDatosMaestrosServiceMessageReceiverInOut.fromOM(CU677ConsultarDatosMaestrosServiceMessageReceiverInOut.java:599)
    at consultardatosmaestros.CU677ConsultarDatosMaestrosServiceMessageReceiverInOut.invokeBusinessLogic(CU677ConsultarDatosMaestrosServiceMessageReceiverInOut.java:44)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.invokeBusinessLogic(AbstractInOutMessageReceiver.java:40)
    at org.apache.axis2.receivers.AbstractMessageReceiver.receive(AbstractMessageReceiver.java:110)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:403)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:151)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at consultardatosmaestros.CU677ConsultarDatosMaestrosServiceMessageReceiverInOut.fromOM(CU677ConsultarDatosMaestrosServiceMessageReceiverInOut.java:472)
```

Comment: any error message printed in wso2carbon.log(<ESB>/repository/logs) ?

Comment: I edited the question with the message printed in wso2carbon.log